# Wordpress -how to return just current month posts on archive.php

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

How to modify the wp_query to take in count post by month as per URL `2012/10/` ?

The following will list **ALL** post, where I just want to list post for `2012/10/`

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(  'posts_per_page' => 10, 'paged' => $paged, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC' );
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a code snippet provided in the link from the earlier answer that says "Returns posts for just the current week". Change "week" for "month", and you got your answer.

The code snippet would look like this:

```
$year = date('Y');
$month = date('n');
$query = new WP_Query( 'year=' . $year . '&monthnum=' . $month );
```

Just read [the link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters). It's all there.

EDIT: If there are further problems returning the month, it may be because the variable needs a [leading zero](http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time). In that case, the $month variable should be

```
$month = date('m');
```

Comment: You can use `date('n')` or `date('m')` - they both work (tested in WP 5).

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with the `year` and `monthnum` parameters, as described in the section [Time Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters) in the class reference:

```
// ... set up your argument array for WP_Query:
$args = array( 
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC' ,
    // add the year/month query here:
    'year' => 2012,
    'monthnum' => 10

    );

$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

// ... and so on
```

Comment: Many thanks, but this is hard coded. Is it possible to keep it dynamic (as per url query)?

Comment: @NewUser: yes you can just replace the numbers with variables/expressions and make it dynamic (like the `paged`-parameter).